# Hard disk power management with image toggling in display

Tags: debian, hard-disk, hardware, power-management

We have a system in which we almost toggle some display data in the screen 24 hours x 7 days a week.

Since our application runs every day, we see some hard disk failures in the field.

Unfortunately, our application specification contains that it should toggle specified data in the screen all time while idle.

To fix this issue:
**Is it possible to power off the hard disk when no user is using it for a certain period time and also make sure display toggles a set of images on the screen?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hdparm` to set how long until a drive spins down. The relevant flags are `-B` (advanced power management feature) and `-S` (standby timeout). For example:

```
# hdparm -S 120 /dev/sda
```

will set the drive to spin down after 10 minutes of inactivity. Note that the value used has a weird interpretation, from the manpage: 1–240 are multiplied by 5 seconds; 241–251 are multiplied by 30 minutes; 252 means 21 minutes; 253 means somewhere between 8 and 12 hours depending on drive vendor; 254 is reserved; 255 means 21 minutes 15 seconds.

You can also immediate spin down the drive with `-y`, or cause it to almost shut off with `-Y`, and check the current mode with `-C`.

Note that you'll have to make sure nothing on the system is routinely accessing the disk. Common suspects include syslog, atime updates, desktop environments, ntpd, etc. You can find them by using the `/proc/sys/vm/block_dump` feature. If you echo 1 to that file, then each access will spit out a message to the kernel log. (Echo 0 to turn it back off). See also [laptop mode](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/laptops/laptop-mode.txt).

Finally, what the screen displays is up to your app—and as long as the images are loaded in memory (or come in via network, or...), that doesn't require hard disk access.

Answer (score 0):

A server, with enough RAM, doesn't even need a harddisk.  You can boot from a SAN/NAS and run everything from memory.  Have you looked into that?